# Flag provided but not defined: -rpc

Tags: geth

Am starting off in blockchain development using the book **Mastering Blockchain - A deep dive into distributed ledgers, consensus protocols, smart contracts, DApps, cryptocurrencies, Ethereum**,

Am using WSL with geth version 1.10.9.

```
$geth version
Geth
Version: 1.10.9-stable
Git Commit: eae3b1946a276ac099e0018fc792d9e8c3bfda6d
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.17
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
```

Am trying to start geth, but am getting the error that the --rpc flag is not defined.

This is the command I am trying to run:

`geth --datadir ~/etherprivate/ --networkid 786 --rpc --rpcapi 'web3,eth,net,debug,personal' --rpccorsdomain '*'`

Any help on how I can solve it?

Comment: Try `geth --help` I didnt find rpc flag in docu for this version

Comment: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options

Comment: Please next time 1) Use https://ethereum.stackexchange.com 2) Do not tag such questions with `go` as they have nothing to do with programming in Go and `blockchain` as they are not about the relevant technology but rather about issues using a particular program. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I will consider doing it next time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The latest versions of Geth (after 1.10.8-stable) do not support *--rpc* but fortunately, as you can see in the [Command-line Options](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options), it has been replaced by the ***--http*** option. So your command should look like this:

```
geth --datadir ~/etherprivate/ --networkid 786 --http --http.api 'web3,eth,net,debug,personal' --http.corsdomain '*'
```

With all *rpc* options replaced by their *http* equivalent:

- --rpc => --http
- --rpcapi => --http.api
- --rpccorsdomain => --http.corsdomain

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears 1.10.9-stable version has a problem and is returning a -rpc error.
GETH 1.10.8-stable version works fine when running the geth command with --rpc

Comment: I am getting the same error, but revert to 1.10.8 does help

Answer (score 1):

You can also use other options related to --rpc

```
  --http                              Enable the HTTP-RPC server
  --http.addr value                   HTTP-RPC server listening interface (default: "localhost")
  --http.port value                   HTTP-RPC server listening port (default: 8545)
  --http.api value                    API's offered over the HTTP-RPC interface
  --http.rpcprefix value              HTTP path path prefix on which JSON-RPC is served. Use '/' to serve on all paths.
  --http.corsdomain value             Comma separated list of domains from which to accept cross origin requests (browser enforced)
  --http.vhosts value                 Comma separated list of virtual hostnames from which to accept requests (server enforced). Accepts '*' wildcard. (default: "localhost")
```